# Ember JS : Make relationships work with multiple files

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I've just begun to work on Ember.js and I'm currently trying to figure out, on a simple example, how relationships work between two models and their associated fixtures.
The two models are contained in two different files :

The first one in a graph.js file:

```
App.Graph= DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    elements: DS.hasMany('element',{ async: true })
});

App.Graph.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id:1,
        title:'Test',
        elements: 1
    }
];
```

The second in an element.js file:

```
App.Element = DS.Model.extend({
    x: DS.attr('string'),
    y: DS.attr('string'),
    graph: DS.belongsTo('graph',{ async: true })
});

App.Element.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id:1,
        x:'10',
        y:'10',
        graph:1
    }
];
```

I simply want to display the coordinates, here is the template :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    {{#each item in model}}
      {{#each item.elements}}
      <ul>
       <li>
        <label>{{x}}</label>
        <label>{{y}}</label>
       </li>
      </ul>
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
 </script>
```

And the associated route :

```
  App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('graph');
  }
});
```

The problem is that I get this error `Error while processing route: test No model was found for 'graph' Error: No model was found for 'graph'`

I suspect that the problem comes with the relationships and the fact that the models are in separate files included in the html file.

I've spent a long time on how to make this work but I don't really know how to handle it.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your time!

Comment: How are you including these files in your application?

Comment: They are in a "models" folder and I include them with the following tags in the html file : <script src="js/models/element.js"/>
  <script src="js/models/graph.js"/>

Comment: When you import like that your ember app still does not know about the model, just your html file does. If you want to develop real and big apps in the future i suggest looking into ember-cli - it has seperate folders for templates, routes... and seperate files for each template, route and so on.

Comment: if you already are using ember-cli, you need to start off each file with i believe *import Ember from "ember";* (I dont have my project code with me so I am not 100% sure)

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I haven't actually used ember-cli in my example, but I think that I'm going to use it now for a more ambitious app.